# Help installing Stata on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I need Stata on my laptop and I'm new to Ubuntu. I have a folder with some taz files but I'm not sure what to do with them. I installed it given the instructions provided but it won't open, it gives me this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgtksourceview-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here are the instructions that it came with

Before starting:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-3.0-common
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgtksourceview-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgtksourceview-1.0.so.0
sudo apt-get install libgnomeprint2.2-0
```

1. Unzip the file Stata12_Linux
2. Choose 32-bits or 64-bits

   ```
   cd YOUR_PATH/Stata12_Linux/linux.32/
   ```

   or

   ```
   cd YOUR_PATH/Stata12_Linux/linux.64/
   ```
3. ```
   tar -xzvf docs.taz
   tar -xzvf base.taz
   tar -xzvf bins.taz
   tar -xzvf ado.taz
   sudo mkdir /usr/local/stata12
   mv * /usr/local/stata12/
   cd /usr/local/stata12/
   sudo chmod -R 755 .
   sudo sh setrwxp now
   sudo ./stinit
   ```

Use the Serial Number, Code and Authorization given by SloveniaX

Congratulations!! Stata 12 is installed.
./xstata

Comment: Symlinking libgtksourceview-2.0 to libgtksourceview-1.0 seems like a bit of a "hail mary pass" to me - regardless, you may need to run `sudo ldconfig` for it to take effect (i.e. for `ld` to re-read the `/usr/lib` directory and cache the link).

Comment: That didn't do anything I don't think

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with the same installation procedure. To be precise, Stata will run through command line (i.e. terminal) after this installation process, but thats pretty useless as one uses Stata only for the friendly GUI, right? For using the GUI, we need the packages `libgnomeprint2.2-0` and `libgtksourceview2.0-0`, which are not supported by Ubuntu 16.04. Solved this by adding the old repositories of Ubuntu 12.04 (the last one to support those packages I believe) into Ubuntu 16.04 apt sources. Open terminal as administrator and:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to the sources.list file that opens up:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
```

Save and close. Update new sources in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the erstwhile unsupported packages using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnomeprint2.2-0 libgtksourceview2.0-0
```

This did it for me. Stata GUI up and running!

P.S. This solution is NOT BY ME. Read http://people.duke.edu/~aql3/install-stata12-ubuntu1404/

P.P.S. Can anyone tell if this procedure has any side-effects? I mean adding old repositories to newer distributions?

Comment: @ Steven Brialsford Do tell if this works for you. Make sure you run ./xstata (for GUI) and not ./stata(for command-line usage).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way!  You can just update to a newer build of Stata 12. 
 To do so, open the non-graphical Stata by running `./stata`, then update with `update query`, then `update all`.

The updated version doesn't depend on libgtksourceview or libgnomeprint.

Here's what it should look like:

```
. update query
(contacting http://www.stata.com)

Update status
    Last check for updates:  28 Feb 2018
    New update available:    23 Jan 2014
    Current update level:    24 Aug 2011

Comment

<Ad for Stata 15 here>


Possible actions

    Updates are available. Type -update all- to install.

. update all
(contacting http://www.stata.com)

downloading executable files ...      complete
downloading documentation files ...   complete
downloading ado files ...             complete

installing executable files ...       complete
installing documentation files ...    complete
installing ado files ...              complete

All files were sucessfully installed.

(!) Stata is about to shutdown this version of
    Stata and automatically launch the new version.
```

As a side note, you don't have to do all the untarring either. You can just run `./install`.