# Stata 14 fails to start on Ubuntu 16.10/17.04/17.10, with "libpng12.so.0" error. How do I install libpng12?

Tags: 16.10, shared-library, libpng

The proprietary software Stata version 14 works fine on LTS 16.04, but I made the mistake of upgrading Ubuntu to 16.10 without thinking about the possibility that proprietary software (Stata is my only one) might break. I can't downgrade.
Stata says:

```
stata-se: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Stata support tells me to install libpng12.

So my question is, how can I safely install and make this library available to Stata?  (Apparently, the Stata GUI won't work perfectly even with the library, but the functionality will be available.)

Trying with apt gives:

> E: Unable to locate package libpng12

`libpng-dev` is already installed, and seems not to fit the need.

I assume Stata support would have told me if an easy fix like this would work, but in trying to fake it with symlinks,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.25.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

made no difference.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.25.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

gave:

```
stata-se: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Comment: Have you tried installing libpng-dev? For 16.10 it's libpng16.so but it might be backwards compatible.

Comment: Yes; it's already installed, and no good. (Question updated; thanks)

Comment: Did you by any chance try making a symlink 12-->16? A bit of a long shot but it might work.

Comment: ` locate libpng16.so.0` gives me nothing, so I'm not sure where it should go. There are:
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.25.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16.25.0

Comment: Updated original Q: got "stata-se: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" with on `ln -s` attempt.

Comment: I wish I had a solution for you. Looking at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/841618/help-installing-stata-on-ubuntu-16-04) and your error makes me wonder if there's a mismatch between the 32 and 64 bit that is having an impact on your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your symlinks won't work because you're creating a link to a i386 library in a path that is commonly searched for amd64 libraries. Executables compiled for one architecture (amd64) can't load shared libraries compiled for another architecture (i386).

<s>You may be able to trick Stata to use libpng16 instead of libpng12 if you ensure that *it's for the same architecture* as the Stata executable itself. I’ll assume that the latter is for amd64 (considering that the error message complains about an invalid ELF class `ELFCLASS32` which is used for i386 instruction sets only).</s>

It looks like Stata explicitly checks the libpng version, so the trick described above and thus the two solutions building upon it below won't work. Refer to the *Better Solution* instead.

### <s>Quick and dirty solution</s>

Masquerade `libpng16.so.16` as `libpng12.so.0` to *all* amd64 executables:

```sh
sudo ln -sfT libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
```

### Still dirty but with fewer future surprises

Masquerade `libpng16.so.16` as `libpng12.so.0` to selected executables only (thus eliminating the risk that another applications picks up the bogus `libpng12.so.0` by mistake):

1. Create a directory for “masquerade” shared libraries, e. g.:

   ```sh
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/stata/shared-library-hack
   ```
2. Place a symbolic link to the masked shared library into it:

   ```sh
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /usr/local/lib/stata/shared-library-hack/libpng12.so.0
   ```
3. Run the program with a modified library search path:

   ```sh
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/stata/shared-library-hack [COMMAND] [ARGUMENTS...]
   ```

   Or if you want to retain potentially existing alterations to the library search path:

   ```sh
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:"}/usr/local/lib/stata/shared-library-hack" [COMMAND] [ARGUMENTS...]
   ```

   If you don't want to type such a long command each time you start such an application, you can either use a shell script wrapper or edit the application starter description (i. e. the `Exec=` stanza in the `.desktop` file) accordingly.

### Better solution

Actually install `libpng12.so.0`. The easiest way is to download and install the Deb package of an earlier Ubuntu release:

1. Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download, pick a mirror and download the package archive.
2. Use your favourite package manager to install the package archive.

   On the command line you can use:

   ```sh
   sudo apt install [DOWNLOAD-PATH]/libpng12-0_*_amd64.deb
   ```

   (Replace `[DOWNLOAD-PATH]` with whichever path you used as the target directory of the download earlier.)

> This is **not** a proper solution, because updates to `libpng12`, including security updates, will not be automatically installed, so doing this introduces a security risk. – [fkraiem Dec 8 '17 at 4:36](/questions/900506/stata-14-fails-to-start-on-ubuntu-16-10-17-04-17-10-with-libpng12-so-0-error/950956#comment1583492_950956)

Comment: Under 17.04: Your "quick and dirty" results in: "stata: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found (required by stata)"

Comment: ...  I then tried your "Proper solution" and stata now launches under 17.04. The icons are missing, but everything else seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Looks like Stata explicitly checks the libpng version. I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is **not** a proper solution, because updates to `libpng12`, including security updates, will not be automatically installed, so doing this introduces a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpler/compact answer:

This is tested for 64bit Stata on a 64bit Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.10 (but seems to fail on 17.04?). Simply:

visit http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download and click on any of the links to mirrors there. This will download `libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`.  Click on this file, or launch it with something like

```
gnome-open ~/Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and click the install button.

Now Stata14 and its xstata will launch fine. The icons will be missing in the menus, but everything else seems to work fine.